# I'm trying to use a method within my class when using a method

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment based on Parking Tickets. I currently have 2 methods and the first one returns a number which is the amount of tickets issued for a specific car license number:

```
public void totalTicketsOfLicense(String issuedLicenseNumber){
    int numberOfTickets = 0;
    Iterator<ParkingTicket> it = tickets.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        ParkingTicket eachTicket = it.next();
        if(eachTicket.getCarLicenseNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(issuedLicenseNumber)){
            numberOfTickets++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The license number: " + issuedLicenseNumber + " has recieved " + numberOfTickets + " tickets.");
}
```

the other method returns a number that calculates the total amount of fines that specific license number has:

```
public double totalTicketFineOfLicense(String issuedLicenseNumber){
    double totalFine = 0.0;
    Iterator<ParkingTicket> it = tickets.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        ParkingTicket eachTicket = it.next();
        if(eachTicket.getCarLicenseNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(issuedLicenseNumber)){
            totalFine = totalFine + eachTicket.getAmountFined();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The license number: " + issuedLicenseNumber + " has recieved " + totalFine + "$ in total fines.");
    return totalFine;
}
```

Now I have to create a final method. This method will have 2 parameters, a double payment and a `String licenseNumber`. If the payment is higher then the totalTicketFineOfLicense then it will return a message telling me how many number of tickets were payed off and change if the **payment was higher** then the `totalTicketFineOfLicense` .

So at this point I'm confused on how to activate the 2 methods above WITHIN this third method I have to write. Which will have the signature:

```
public double payParkingTickets(double paymentInCAD, String licenseNumber)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried calling the 2 methods but that wouldnt work if I inputted a different license number. I have no idea on what functions I'd use nore have I been able to find anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call a method in the same class directly, for example here is a start to writing your third method

```
public double payParkingTickets(double paymentInCAD, String licenseNumber){
    final double totalFines = totalTicketFineOfLicense(licenseNumber);
    if(totalFines <= paymentInCAD){
        ...handle what to do if payment is more than the fines...
    } 
}
```

Comment: all i had to do was put the licenseNumber into the parameters of totalTicketFineOfLicense thats what I was looking for thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're trying to use both methods; based on what you posted, I'm not sure you need to call totalTicketsOfLicense() in payParkingTickets().

If your question is just about calling a method from another method, you can do that by writing "methodName(parameters)" in your code, so in your case something like

```
public double payParkingTickets(double paymentInCAD, String licenseNumber) {
    double totalFine = totalTicketFineOfLicense(licenseNumber);
    // do something
    ...
}
```

Comment: awesome mtheodName(paramters) was what I was looking for thank you very much!